# Ionicons show question mark and Open-Sans font not loaded, ​after 'expo publish release-channel' command

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

1. SDK Version: 47.0.0
2. Platforms(Android/iOS/web/all): iOS and Android

So, in a CI/CD jenkins pipeline, the final step publishes my app in a channel.
Unfortunately when the app published run on my iPhone through the qrcode, I got an app with all icons showed as question mark and *open-sans* custom fonts is missing as well.

If I publish manually from my laptop, in any channel, same app is showing icons and fonts correctly.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.11",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "6.5.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.4.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.5.3",
    "@stripe/stripe-react-native": "0.19.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "common": "file:../common/common-1.0.0.tgz",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.3",
    "expo": "^47.0.12",
    "expo-app-loading": "^2.1.1",
    "expo-camera": "~13.1.0",
    "expo-font": "^11.0.1",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.0.2",
    "expo-media-library": "~15.0.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.17.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "expo-updates": "~0.15.6",
    "jotai": "^1.9.2",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.8",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.8",
    "react-native-dropdown-select-list": "^2.0.4",
    "react-native-element-dropdown": "^2.7.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.8.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scrollview": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-pager-view": "6.0.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.18.0",
    "react-native-swipe-list-view": "^3.2.9",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-uuid": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@faker-js/faker": "^7.6.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.1",
    "@types/react": "~18.0.24",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.70.6"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

This is **how I use Ionicons**:

```
// Some code...
import Ionicons from '@expo/vector-icons/Ionicons';

// Other code...
<TouchableOpacity onPress={ ()=> props.navigation.toggleDrawer() }>
   <Ionicons name="person-circle" size={80} />
</TouchableOpacity>
// Other code...
```

This is **how I load custom fonts** from the /assets/fonts:

```
// ...
const fetchFonts = () => {
    return Font.loadAsync({
        "open-sans":        require("../assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf"),
        "open-sans-bold":   require("../assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf")
    });
};

useEffect(() => {
    // After the custom fonts have loaded, we can hide 
    // the splash screen and display the app screen.
    const prepare = async () => {
        try {
            await fetchFonts();
        } catch (e) {
            console.warn(e);
        } finally {
            // Tell the application to render
            setFontsLoaded(true);
        }
    }
   // ...
   prepare();
}, []);
// ...
```

And this is a **screenshot** of the issue:

So, in my Jenkins pipeline, I do these steps to publish a release on a channel:

1. `npm install -g eas-cli --no-progress`
2. `npm install -g expo-cli --no-progress`
3. `eas login`
4. `expo publish --release-channel <name-of-my-channel>`

I read all of topics related but unsuccessfully anything solve it.
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance